# How can I remove the smell of egg from my hands?

Tags: kitchen, smell

Whenever I baked something like cake and used eggs in this, the smell of egg remains on my hand even after I washed my hand, which irritates me a lot. What could be remedies to remove this smell quickly?

Comment: I never experienced the effect you describe (and I bake and cook *a lot*). What kind of eggs are you using and how are you storing them? How do you get egg on your hands in the first place and how much?

Comment: when I put it over baking plate and also when mixing it with baking material

Comment: ofcourse i also used hen's eggs.

Comment: @banneenbeno As opposed to rooster eggs? :P

Answer (score 1):

I use the juice of a lemon to remove smells from my hands after eating crab.  It might work for eggs, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think toothpaste is the best for removing any type of smell from hands.it is quickly solution for best results .take some toothpaste and apply on your hands ,wait for two minutes then wash it.